# Custom shader - Three.js

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I am trying to use a custom shader with Three.js. I tried to do it like the many examples, but it doesn't work. My code is:

```
var vertex = "void main(){vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0    );gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;}";
var fragment = "precision highp float;void main(void){gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);}";
material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
                vertexShader: vertex,
                fragmentShader: fragment
        });
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
```

…and everything is blank. But if I use this material :

```
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true });
```

…everything works perfectly. What's wrong?

Comment: It works fine for me. It must be some other piece of code you aren't showing.

Comment: Couldbe there some problem with geometry? I am loading that like array of vertices and indices, but with MeshBasic material it works great..i will try to find it deeper in my code..

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem: I had to use:

```
 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
```

instead of :

```
 renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
```